# I want to use my app for global network

Tags: yammer

We have created an app on Yammer which is currently private.

We want to make it available and accessible to networks outside us. Please suggest if there is a way to get it authenticated by outside network or do we have to go by the process of submitting the app to Yammer support for global access.

If that is the case, please help us know how much time does it require to get reviewed and approved as it is almost a week and we have not heard back from Yammer support.

Comment: Please note that this is a community-driven Q&A site, [not an official support forum for any third-party product](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support).

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the app to Yammer's App Directory for approval. Depending on your app you may also be able to allow users to configure their own Client ID, but this is really only a usable approach for developers or system admins. End users wouldn't understand how to do that.